# PHP Socket Send Message On Disconnect?

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flash, sockets

I have me a socket created in PHP that I am connecting to in flash/as3. Its working 99%, but...

```
$bytes = socket_recv($socket, $buffer, 2048, 0);
if ($bytes == 0) {
    //User disconnects
    $index = array_search($socket, $read_sockets);
    $tehEC = socket_last_error();
    $CID = $read_sockets[$index];
    $DNAME = $DB->db->query("SELECT * FROM chat_online WHERE connectid='$CID'");
    $BROW = $DB->db->fetch_array($DNAME);
    $BNAME = $BROW['user_name'];
    $DB->db->query("DELETE FROM chat_online WHERE connectid='$CID'");
    echo "dc " . $tehEC . "\n";
    send_Message($allclients, $socket, $BNAME . ": /disconnected " . $BNAME); <-- WILL NOT SEND
    unset($read_sockets[$index]);
    send_Message($allclients, $socket, $BNAME . ": /disconnected " . $BNAME); <-- WILL NOT SEND 
    socket_close($socket);
}
```

So I have been able to get an event to fire when a user disconnects and all, but that line not sending makes my life really hard :( any help please? I need it to send that to the other clients so I can remove the users. So again, how can I get the socket server to send a message to all still online clients so they know to remove the disconnected user from the list.

Comment: What do you do in send_Message()? What are $allclients? You're passing $socket - are you sending the message to that $socket? If you are, then that's the problem - you are sending to the user that disconnected.

Comment: Crossdomain.xml is not being handled and I assume the master is not set up either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem was I needed to add chr(0) to the end of the string to get it to send. Thank you for the responses though.